# Add preload to a styleseet included in asset-pipeline

Tags: css, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, preload

I have a page on my website (made on Ruby on Rails), for which I want to increase the performance. I am using "Audits" of Google Chrome to test the "Preformance".

One of the things that I am getting in "Opportunities" section are: "Pre-load key requests". What it is telling me is, to use use preload for some of the CSS which are taking time. What I am unable to understand here is that, the CSS that it is telling me to preload is in application.scss file. How do I preload a CSS which is getting pre-compiled? Is that even possible?

What I know is that if I am using a stylesheet say, temp.css on a page, I can use

```
link rel="preload" href="temp.scss" as="style"
```

and it will preload the file. Now, how do I do this for an asset which is getting pre-compiled. I am really confused. Kindly help if my understanding is wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preload_link_tag`. Refer here:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-preload_link_tag

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `rel: :preload` at end of your `stylesheet_link_tag`, like:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', rel: :preload %>
```

It will generate on HTML header something like:

```
<link rel="preload" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-ddcad.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload">
```